# Is there anyway we can convert a .doc to .ppt format?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, documents

Is there anyway we can convert a `.doc` to `.ppt` format?  Please let me know we if have some kind of software available to convert?

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140123%28office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs) from your favorite programming language? Perhaps you can upload a .doc and download a .ppt, programatically?